# Spring @Value can not get system property

Tags: java, spring

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class PropertyReader {
    @Value("${spring.active.profiles")
    private String profile;

    @Nonnull
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
}
```

and this is test I have

```
public class PropertyReaderTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetProfile() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertEquals("development", new PropertyReader().getProfile());
    }
}
```

and the dependency I have is

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and I see

```
development
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :development
Actual   :null
```

Comment: You are constructing a new instance of the class yourself. Spring isn't in play anywhere so will not do injection/replacement of any kind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate of Why is my Spring @Autowired field null.  The cause of this null is differennt.

Comment: It isn't, the same issue applies in both cases a new instance (outside of Spring) is created.

Answer (score 1):

first thing i am assuming your syntax is correct and its type mistake for @value that you have posted.

```
 @Value("${spring.active.profiles}")
```

Now to use @value, you must make the class register as a spring bean and that too using only annotation. even if you register class using xml also your @value will not work.

and also get the bean using spring container to happen automatic injection, dont create object by yourselves using new.

Solution to your above problem

1)

```
@Component
PropertyReader
```

make class PropertyReader  as a spring bean using @Component.

2)load bean from application context in your test class, dont use new to create it.

Comment: I do not have any application context, I am using annotations

Comment: if its a spring project, then where you have put context:component-scan tag ?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I am using spring in my maven dependency<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: see @value is the spring EL feature, so get it work we need to make the containing class as  a spring bean. you can do that even without xml config but ofcourse you need to use java side config for spring

Answer (score 0):

Yuo should put @Service on the class PropertyReader or you should use a XML spring file in order to define the bean and let to spring to valorize properties